# Insert data into Datagridview from comboboxes and textboxes to a specific row

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, datagridview, windows-forms-designer

So basically what I want to do is to select data from the combo boxes, and write something in the textboxes, and when I press the button all these data will fill the proper places of the datagridview.

I only found codes that fill up rows that are next to each other but I would have to write some logic for them to fill specific rows or don't fill them on certain values

```
        private void fill_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        table.Rows.Add(combo1.Text, combo2.Text, combo3.Text, text1.Text);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
    
    }
```

This code only does the trick if these rows and values are supposed to be next to each other. But in my case, they don't.

How can I refer to a specific row that I want to fill?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are adding a "new" ROW to the table, so I am not sure what you mean by “specific” row? I assume you mean a “specific column” in a new row? If that is the case then this  should work…

```
DataRow dr = table.NewRow();
// by column Name...
dr["Name"] = combo1.Text;
// or by index
int colIndex = 3;
dr[colIndex] = text1.Text;
// then add the row;
table.Rows.Add(dr);
```

Comment: Thank you very much!